# Why would image thumbnails not be showing in all search engines in all browsers?

Tags: browser, thumbnails, search-engines

For over a week now, when I search for a word at **Google**, it correctly gives me **some** preview image thumbnails:

[image]

But when I click on "**images**", it doesn't show me any thumbnails:

[image]

The same thing happens at **Bing.com**, when I search Bing itself it gives me some thumbnails on the general search result page:

[image]

But when I click on "**images**", it doesn't show me any thumbnails:

[image]

The same thing happens at **Yahoo**:

[image]

If I click on one of the broken thumbnails, it **shows me the picture fine**:

[image]

Thumbnails at **YouTube** also work **fine**:

[image]

It seems each search engine is **hanging on different URLs** as shown above:

- t1.gstatic.com
- ts3.mm.bing.net
- thm-a02.yimg.com

so it doesn't seem to be the problem of one specific URL not sending thumbnails, it is just a **problem with search engine image thumbnails in general.**

Also, this happens in every browser I try: **Explorer, Firefox, Chrome**.

**What could be the problem? Is it my computer, some setting somewhere, my router, my Internet provider (T-Online, Germany)? Has anyone ever had this problem and solved it?**

## ADDED:

When I copy the URL of one of the thumbnails and paste it into the URL bar, after about 30 seconds it gives me this error:

[image]

But pings to these domains work:

[image]

## ADDED:

During the **past months** I noticed this happening from **time to time**, but then it would work again, but now search machine image thumbnails have **not worked consistently for a week**.

## ADDED:

I tried it on **another computer** connected to the same router: **same problem**. Also in **virtual machines** it has the **same problem**.

## ADDED:

Ok, I'm plugged in here at a hotel lobby now and image thumbsnails work just fine. I think the problem is T-Online. Is anyone else having the problem with them? Will get on it when I get back.

Comment: Are you running adblock, etc.? Try disabling it or using a 'clean' browser that doesn't have any plugins installed.

Comment: To further diagnose the problem, right-click on one of the thumbnails, select Properties, and highlight and copy the address of the actual thumbnail image. Then paste that address into the address box and enter it to see what kind of error message you get. Another test you can try is to open a command prompt and ping the domain names that seem to have problems (t1.gstatic.com, ts3.mm.bing.net, thm-a02.yimg.com).

Comment: @Nitrodist I have no adblock apps, @Bavi_H going directly to the images gives me a connection timed out on all of them so that seems to be the problem, pings to the domains however work fine. Is there something in my DNS that I can check or change?

Comment: It's probably your ISP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it happens on different machines, then it isn't a case of some security software is blocking the access. As the router is the common factor in your network, it could be some setting of it that has gone wrong, such as the firewall.

You could:

1. Connect the portable on another network, outside of your home, and see if this still happens.
2. Try another router
3. Reset the router to factory defaults.

The information from these tries should add to our understanding of the problem.

Comment: I replaced that (5 year old) router with a new one and everything works wonderfully now.

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts on what might help to diagnose it:-

1. Try the same thing with another PC on your router.
2. Try going to sites using your laptop but elsewhere (e.g. wifi hotspot).
3. Try using another browser.

Comment: it does the same thing on the laptop connected through the same router (LAN cable). it does the same thing in virtual machines (VMWare), it is the same for all browsers, all 3 search machines, only for image thumbnails, and both German and English versions of the search machines